# How to obtain specific arrays from a nested Dictionary and maintain its integrity when changing them to a ndarry, sparse matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to put different document matrices into a sklearn cosine similarity that takes in a {ndarray, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples_X, n_features) but i'm stuck.

The documents are in a nested dictionary like the following...

```
#This is called tfidf_ten_ks
{2020: {'negative': array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]),
  'positive': array([[0.20504584, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
          0.06834861, 0.08543577, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
```

I want to grab all the arrays for 'negative' for all the years and then put them through the cosine similarity, and so on for the remaining features. I'm able to collect them together but i think my method is wrong or i need to create a function that alters the cosine similarity function.

```
x=[]
for date in dates:
    x.append(tfidf_ten_ks[date]['negative'])
#putting the list back into an array
x=np.asarray(x)
```

Here the length of x is 9, how it should be. However, for me to put it into the cosine similarity function i need to reshape it. After reshaping(-1,1) the length becomes 2195 or using reshape(1,-1) the length becomes 1. The prior gives me back an array 2194 by 2194 and the latter gives me a 1 by 1 after putting them into the cosine function.

The goal is to get each documents similarity wrt to each other. Therefore, a 9x9.
How can i retrieve their arrays from the dictionary, to then implement them into the cosine similarity function to only obtain in my case, a 9x9 array of their correlation?

Any help would be really appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: What is 9?  The number of `dates`?  Do those `negative' arrays vary in size?  What is the `dtype`?

Comment: Yes, 9 is the number of years. so the first key refers to the year, its value is another dictionary. The length of the arrays are the same size and i'm assuming the dtype is a numpy.ndarray object. i basically want to collect all the negative arrays (total 9) then put them through the function to get back a 9 by 9, which will give there correlation wrt each other. Any guidance would be great, thanks!

Comment: Examine `x` on both sides of this: `x=np.asarray(x)`.  Don't just check `shape`.  Look at `dtype`, and look some of the elements.  Do you have a new enough numpy version to get a `ragged array` warning?

Comment: x dtype is 'float64', the shape is (9, 1, 2355). I'm assuming the problem lies in the fact it is not a (9, 2355)? Since i need to it to be a 2d array, not a 3d. i checked individually too, straight from the dictionary and they all have the same length.

Comment: Oh, so the `shape` is 3d - a 3 tuple.  Your initial focus on `length`, which is just the 1st dimension mislead me.  You get that middle size 1 dimension because the individual arrays have shape (1,2355).  See the initial '[['?  There are various ways to get rid of that, reshape to (9,2355), (9,-1) or (-1,2355), or `np.squeeze`, or `x[:,0]`.

Comment: THANK YOU! Yeah i figured that was causing the issue so i was trying to get rid of it using convoluted methods. It was an easy fix with the np.squeeze. Wow, i should go learn some numpy lol. Thanks once again!